# Extending class variable does not exist on properties

Tags: apex, inheritance, polymorphism

I defined a virtual class and two classes that extend it with additional properties.

After creating the class instance and trying to initialize it's properties i get a "Variable does not exist" error on the properties of the extending class.

Code examples

The class definition:

```
public virtual class BpmPayment {
public Payment__c payment { get; set; }
public String sum { get; set; }

public class TransferPayment extends BpmPayment {
    public Date transferDate { get; set; }
}

public class CheckPayment extends BpmPayment {
    public String bank { get; set; }
    public String branch { get; set; }
    public String serial { get; set; }
    public Date repaymentDate { get; set; }
}
}
```

Initializing:

```
newCheckPayment.sum = String.valueOf(newPayment.Paid_Amount__c);
newCheckPayment.payment = newPayment;                    
newCheckPayment.repaymentDate = date.valueOf(checkDate);
```

The "sum" and "payment" properties are resolved just fine (i'm guessing because they belong to the outer class)
But i get the error for the "repaymentDate" property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what instance is the `newCheckPayment`.

I think you should make something like:

```
BpmPayment.CheckPayment newCheckPayment = new BpmPayment.CheckPayment();
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried to reproduce this with a minimal example and found that property resolution on the inner subclass works fine:

```
public virtual class Superclass {
    public String superProperty { get; set; }

    public class Subclass extends Superclass {
        public String subProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Running

```
Superclass s = new Superclass();

s.superProperty = 'Test';
System.assertEquals('Test', s.superProperty);

Superclass.Subclass sc = new Superclass.Subclass();

sc.superProperty = 'Test';
sc.subProperty = 'Test-Sub';

System.assertEquals('Test', sc.superProperty);
System.assertEquals('Test-Sub', sc.subProperty);
```

All of the assertions pass.

I suspect that the issue you have here is outside the code that you shared, and it's one of two things. Either:

- You declared your variable as an instance of `BpmPayment`, rather than `BpmPayment.CheckPayment`. The superclass doesn't have the property (which is checked at compile time), even if you're actually assigning an instance of a subclass that does.
- There's a separate, unrelated syntax error nearby in your code, which can sometimes manifest as "no such variable" type errors.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It was very informative, had to mark Enrik since he answered first though, i tried to upvote but i don't have enough reputation.